# Convexity analysis

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

I know that summation of two convex functions is also convex but I would like to know that does the same holds true for non-convex functions also such that the summation of two non-convex functions also non-convex?

Comment: $\sin$ and $-\sin$ are non convex but $ \sin - \sin = 0$ is convex.

Comment: So it really depends on the non-convex functions itself. If there are two same functions that are non-convex wrt a common variable and we take the summation of those two functions is the resultant function non-convex also?

Comment: I think you can check that yourself in a straightforward manner :-).

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration I will check it but I think it would be non-convex. :-)

Comment: If you multiply a non convex function by a positive number it will still be non convex. Adding a function to itself is the same as multiplying by $2$.

Comment: Very logical point thank you so much. I was thinking of applying Sylvester's criteria you saved me a lot of time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Sum of two non-convex functions can be a convex function. Consider the following:
$$\
f(x)=x^4-2x^3 \ , \ \ g(x)=2x^3
$$
We see that $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)=x^4$ is a convex function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's because the second term of the first function contains the opposite of the second function and the first term itself is convex. Generally speaking, my problem was different as I checked the convexity of two functions w.r.t. a single variable and by exploiting symmetry i was able to add them together. If one scales a non-convex function by 2 it's still non-convex. Conclusion depending on the two non-convex functions their summation can or cannot be non-convex.

Comment: @Ali note that in my example $f$ and $g$ both are non-convex functions. Also, I don't understand what you mean by convexity of two functions w.r.t. a single variable. But your conclusion is correct. The sum may or may not be convex.